# How to make Logcat show actual debugs rather than processes?

Tags: android-studio, logcat

As the title suggests, A couple of days ago I probably accidentaly pressed some buttons which screwed up my Logcat. Whenever I run my code, in my Logcat is doesn't show any of the debugs or types of debugs, but rather just random proccesses of the code. Here is what I mean:

[image: This is what is showed for me]

However, this is what I want to happen when I open Logcat:

[image: Exactly like this, with the whole Verbose and filters section and stuff, basically the default of Logcat]

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I have been using Logcat quite a lot and I haven't found any fixes. Thanks in advance!

I haven't really tried anything, searching online didn't result in anything as there isn't really a good way to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using at least Android Studio Dolphin where the new [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#logcat) has been enabled. If you look closely, the information you're seeking is present in the new Logcat as well.

Also make sure to use the filters according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#logcat-search).

If you'd like to conform to the new changes later, just download an older version of Android Studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).

Answer (score 0):

Logcat has been updated. Previous logcat was easier for me to read and understand. You may read official documentation about patch here: [https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#logcat-search](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases)
Now you should use something like this to filter logs:

```
package:mine tag:Activity level:VERBOSE
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr0wf.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).